# When do pointers change?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand pointer arithmetic and I thought I got it.
When do pointers change?

They cannot be increased/decreased by `ptr[-4]` neither by `*(ptr + 5)`, but `ptr++`, `++ptr`.

I tried some code and I stumbled upon this:
Why is it suddenly decreasing, or do not add up to `6`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char i[] = "1234567890";
    char *c = &i[1];

    printf("Start:\n");
    printf("%c\n", *c); // 2
    printf("%c\n", ++(*c)); // 3 
    printf("%c\n", *c); // 3
    printf("%c\n", ++(*c)); // 4
    printf("%c\n", *c); // 4
    printf("%c\n", *++c); //3
    printf("%c\n", *c); // 3
    printf("%c\n", *++c); // 4
    printf("%c\n", *c); // 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `++(*c)` is incrementing the char, not the pointer.

Comment: @stark I thought so too, but then why is the next `printf("%c\n", *c);` printing 3 and not 2?

Comment: Regarding knowing when the pointer changed (as opposed to what it points to), you can always just use `%p` and print the value of the pointer if you want to see it. Or single step through your code in a *debugger* and watch the value of `c` (as well as the value of `*c`).

Comment: @stark but does *++c increase the pointer?

Comment: @tgtrmr Of course it does. That's what `++c` does.

Comment: `*++c` is equivalent to `*(++c)`. So it increments the pointer, then dereferences the new value.

Comment: `printf("%c\n", ++(*c)); // 3 ` This increments the character. The array now looks `"1334567890"` and after `printf("%c\n", ++(*c)); // 4` it looks like this: `"1434567890"`

Comment: @tgtrmr Printing the content of `i` using `%s` in each of those output lines would probably be helpful in understanding what is going on. The first five relevant lines report on, and change, the value at `i[1]`. The next line moves `c` to point to `i[2]`. The line after that just regurgitates the value reported on the prior line (`c` still points to `i[2]`). The last two lines repeat that process, moving `c` to point to `i[3]`, reporting the dereference, then reporting it again. Stepping through with a debugger make everything I just said crystal clear.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - `c` doesn't change, it's just that incrementing the code point of `'2'` produces the code point of `'3'`. They must be sequential.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks, man! That helped a lot!

Comment: See [question 4.3](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/unopprec2.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Ah...`++(*c)` means to increment the character at `*c` and then use this changed value for `printf`. But now I am confused as how to write "get the char at `c`, increment it and print it? (using `++`, not using `+1`)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If you mean without changing the value of the original char, then the answer is that you can't do it using `++`

Comment: If you want to know when the pointer change its value why don't you just print the value after each step? Like: `printf("%p\n", (void*)c);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing the contents and not the pointer.
This version shows the contents and the offset of the pointer into the contents of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char i[] = "1234567890";
    char *c = &i[1];

    printf("Start:\n");
    printf("%c\n", *c); // 2
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", ++(*c)); // 3 
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", *c); // 3
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);


    printf("%c\n", ++(*c)); // 4
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", *c); // 4
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", *++c); //3
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", *c); // 3
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", *++c); // 4
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);

    printf("%c\n", *c); // 4
    printf("%s %d\n",i,c - &i[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

It produces...

```
2                                                                                                                       
1234567890 1                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                       
1334567890 1                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                       
1334567890 1                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                       
1434567890 1                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                       
1434567890 1                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                       
1434567890 2                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                       
1434567890 2                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                       
1434567890 3                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                       
1434567890 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of your program.  It prints the array `i[]`, and an indication of where the pointer `c` is pointing, after each step.  (That pointer indication is printed a little trickily; I'll explain in a minute.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char i[] = "1234567890";
    char *c = &i[1];

    printf("Start:\n");
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", ++(*c));
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", ++(*c));
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *++c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *++c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    printf("%c\n", *c);
    printf("%s\n", i); printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this, it should help you see when `c` has moved and when it hasn't.  It should help you see where `c` points when the pointed-to character has been modified.

The trick is the call

```
printf("%*s^\n", (int)(c-i), "");
```

The idea here is to print a `'^'` character offset from the left margin by a distance equivalent to the position `c` in the array `i`.  If `c` points to the beginning of `i`, we want to print 0 spaces, then `^`.  If `c` points one cell into `i`, we want to print one space, then `^`.  And so on.  The printf format `%*s` prints a string in a field with a width given by an argument.  I'm using that to print N spaces.  The argument I give it is `c-i`, which is the number of spaces I want to print.  The string I tell it to print is `""`, the empty string.  I'm telling it to print the empty string in a field of width N, so its padding spaces (the ones printf adds to pad the string out to a width of N) are all that it prints, and all that I want it to print.  Then I print the `^`, and it comes out in the right spot.